# Apply function when any checkboxes are changed

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I have an HTML form with checkboxes like so:

```
<form id="filterOptions" method="post" action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="filterTaxi" id="filterTaxi" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="filterBicycle" id="filterBicycle" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="filterCarPark" id="filterCarPark" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="filterBed" id="filterBed" />
</form>
```

Now I want to use javascript to apply a function whenever a checkbox is changed.
At the moment I can apply a function when the first checkbox is changed like so:

```
document.getElementById('filterTaxi').onchange = function(){
  //do something here
};
```

So my question is, how do I avoid writing that for every checkbox and instead have a function fired when any of the checkboxes are changed?

Comment: You have to bind an event handler for every element, but they can all reference the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either select all input or add a class and do:

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i].onchange = function() {
         console.log(this);   
    }
 }
```

onchange function can be the same for all of them.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XgS9K/

Comment: I'd advice to add a class and select all elements with that class.. otherwise you'd select ALL input which might not be what you want ;)

Comment: Cool. I've added a bit to the 'input' variable declaration to make it more specific using your method: `document.getElementById('filterOptions').getElementsByTagName('input')`

Answer (score 0):

for all elements.

```
document.getElementById('filterOptions').onchange = function(){
 alert()
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the `onchange` handler for checking and unchecking of  `checkbox`es.

```
var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
    if (allInputs[i].type == 'checkbox') {
        allInputs[i].onchange = function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                // your checked code here
                console.log('checked');
            } else {
                // your unchecked code here
                console.log('unchecked');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/L324t/